# registration of clients with list

Tags: python

I need to make a function for client registration where the client's username must be unique. I made a `dict` and a `list` where I put everything from my `txt` file, and now I've been trying to set `for` and `while` loops, but it isn't going well:

```
client_list = []

def c_l():
    with open("svi.txt","r") as f:
        pieces = ["username","password","name","lastname","role"]
        for r in f.readlines():
            dicct = {}
            bla = r.strip().split("|")
            count = 0
            for i in bla:
                dicct[pieces[count]] = i
                count += 1
            client_list.append(dicct)

c_l()

def reg():
    for r in client_list:
        while True:
            username = input("Username: ")
            if (username == r["username"] ):
                print("Username is already taken, please try again: ")
            else:
                break

password = input("Your password:")
name = input("Your name: ")
lastname = input("Your lastname: ")

client = username + "|" + password + "|" + name + "|" + lastname + "|" + "buyer"

with open("svi.txt","a") as f:

    f.write(client)
reg()
```

When I was typing this function for the first time, I made all in one function, where I opened the file, typed code for unique username and then printed client into that `txt` file. In that function my `while` loop worked, because all I had to do is to split the parts of the file and index the right one, then make this `while` loop, which worked fine. But now I've been told that I have to do it by using `dict` and `list` and I tried doing this, I don't know what the problem is with my approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to load usernames into a [set](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sets.html) which ensures uniqueness. Then, in your reg function check whether the new username is in the set, like:

```
if username in myset:
    raise InvalidUsernameError
else:
    myset.add(username)
```